# Vimエディタ内かUbuntuのTerminal内でプログラムコードの変数を表示するツールはありませんか？

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

UbuntuでC/C++とPythonを使用しています｡ Jupyter NotebookでVariable Inspectorという拡張機能を知って以来､変数を表示してデバックを行えるツールを探しています｡

pycharmやCLionというIDEがあるらしいですが、Vimのsyntasticの様な構文チェック機能の導入難易度が個人的に高かったのと、Vimのプラグインやコマンドやキーバインドに慣れているため、できるだけ今の環境を維持したまま使用できるプラグインまたはツールをそれぞれの言語環境で探しています｡

Variable Inspectorと違って行列の表示ができれば良いのですがリアルタイム性があると助かります｡ご存知の方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか？ よろしくお願いします｡

なお、この質問は以下のサイトでも同じ質問を行っています。
ご了承の上回答いただけると幸いです｡
https://qiita.com/freqalbeltokei/items/ae814d55e1e0d61e1d89
https://teratail.com/questions/180016

Comment: 想定しているプログラミング言語はPythonでしょうか？質問は後からでも [編集] できますので、追記してみてください。

Comment: 今のところはpythonですがc/c++も近いうちに使います｡

Answer (score 0):

ターミナルで良ければ、[ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) なら [python](/questions/tagged/python), [c](/questions/tagged/c)/[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) それぞれに標準で `pdb` (Python3 だと `pdb3`), `gdb` コマンドが有ります。
また、`lldb`もインストールすることで使うことができます。

使いやすいとは言いにくいですが、Vimならterminalモードで連携ができます。
特に`gdb`にはVim内に標準で`Termdebug`コマンドが用意されていますので、カスタマイズしてやれば、それなりに使えると思います。

Answer (score 0):

なぜ Vim＆Terminalなのでしょうか？
シリアル接続 or SSH接続ですか？
それとも Vimキー操作が望ましいですか？

Terminal editor且つ IDEならば, Vim/Emacsが挙げられます
SSHということなら VS Code あるいは sshfsなどが使えます
(VS Codeは条件があるのでそのまま使えるかは不明)

---

#### 追記

(「Terminal」の理由が不明なので, とりあえず保留に)

Terminal という条件を無視すれば, 普通に jupyter,
あるいは [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) を使うとよいでしょう。

VS Codeに Python拡張をインストールすれば, Variable Inspectorと同様の機能 [Variable explorer and data viewer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_variable-explorer-and-data-viewer) が使えます。
Vimのキーバインディングは [Vim emulation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) があります
拡張のインストールは, 紹介動画にあるように 画面左端に並ぶアイコンから該当するものを選ぶだけ

参考: (抜粋)
[VS Codeドキュメント](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/)

- はじめに

  - [紹介ビデオ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/introvideos)
  - [キーバインディング](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)
- ユーザーガイド

  - [拡張機能マーケットプレイス](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery)

    - [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)
    - [Vim emulation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim)
- プログラミング言語

  - [Python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python)
- Python

  - [Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)
  - [Variable explorer and data viewer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_variable-explorer-and-data-viewer)

---

Vim を IDEとして扱う設定は, それなり難しいようなので, その手順を知りたいという質問なら その様に尋ねないとわかりません

また, もしも dockerあるいは(クラウド PC 含む)リモートマシンにアクセスするために terminal条件があるのなら, いくつか手法があります。
単に terminalを扱いたいだけなら, [統合ターミナル](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) があります。

Comment: IDEに不慣れであるため、Vimを使いたいという前提での質問のようです。また、SSH云々は質問文にないため、この回答はやや的外れに感じます。

Comment: queu1829さんは, 普通に Jupyter使っているようで, 
だったら Jupyter使えばいいはず (他にもそう指摘してる人も)
VS Codeもお勧め …Variable Inspectorと同じ様にできる(Python拡張入れれば)
Vim emulation拡張もある。

で, なぜそこで "Terminal" が出てくるのか？
dockerやcloud pcでも使ってるのか？(その場合 sshになるだろう)
その辺りはっきりさせて欲しい, ということ

Comment: デバッガー操作に慣れているのなら pdb https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/pdb.html
(C/C+ ならば gdb/lldb 辺り)
もう少し高度に連携取りたいなら IDEになるでしょう。IDEに不慣れ, というよりsyntasticの導入難易度が高かった, という話です